# Class variable availablility after event is fired

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling, scope

I'm new to event programming, and I'm obviously misunderstanding something that I'm trying to do.

I have a Windows Forms application that subscribes to events from another class. T

```
//Class that provides event handler to Windows Forms application.
class Foo
{
  public string Value{get; set;}

  // Lots of other code

  public void OnEventFired(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     // Attempt to access variable Value here.
  }    
}
```

From the Windows Form code I'm first setting the variable `Value` in class `Foo` before triggering the event that will execute the code in `OnEventFired` above.

What I'm seeing is that when used in the event handler the variable `Value` doesn't contain the value that was set before the event was fired (`Value` is null).

I know I can extend `EventArgs` to include the variable data, but I'm trying to understand why what I'm doing doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. This certainly *should* be fine. I suspect it's to do with how you're hooking up the event.

Comment: I guess the problem is where you create the instance of the class and how the event is fired. the problem is not about this code certainly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a short example which works. Compare this to your code to work out what's wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Foo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Control)sender).Text = Value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo { Value = "Done" };

        Button button = new Button { Text = "Click me!" };
        button.Click += foo.HandleClick;

        Form form = new Form
        {
            Controls = { button }
        };

        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

My *guess* is that you've hooked up the event handler using a different instance of `Foo` than the one you've set `Value` in. For example, like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo { Value = "Done" };           
...
// Different instance of Foo!
button.Click += new Foo().HandleClick;
```

... but it's hard to tell without seeing any more code.

Comment: Thanks, I've just realised that this is what I was doing. I just got caught up in the idea that I wasn't understanding the event driven code properly.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason that you can not access the variable `Value` is

> 1. `Value` is not set
> 2. You are binding `event` to a different instance, not the one with the `Value` been set.

The best would be to get the `Value` in constructor, so that it is guaranteed that the `Value` is set.

```
class Foo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Foo(Value value)
    {

    }

    public void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Control)sender).Text = Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Asif, I appreciate your answer.